# Transversality on manifolds

Tags: manifolds, transversality

Let be $M^{n}$ a differentiable manifold and $N_{1}$,$N_{2}$ two submanifolds of $M$. We say that $N_{1}$ and $N_{2}$ intersect transversely if $N_{1} \cap N_{2} = \emptyset$ or for all $p \in N_{1} \cap N_{1} $, then $T_{p}N_{1}+ T_{p}N_{2} = T_{p}M$. Show that $S^{1}$ is transversal to any straight line in $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ passing thought the origin.

My idea is to parameterize the two submanifolds, for example for the line denote

$l$ = $ \{ y- ax : a \in  \mathbb{R} \}$ and $\frac{{\partial l}}{{\partial y}} = 1$ and $\frac{{\partial l}}{{\partial x}} = a$ and then consider the spam of the derivates, and do the same for $S^{1}$.

I appreciate your ideas,
Thank you

Comment: That seems fine. Go ahead and do it!

Comment: No, I don't know what you mean by the span of the derivatives. You want the $1$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ tangent to $\ell$ at $p$ and the $1$-dimensional subspace tangent to $S^1$ at $p$ (with $p$ the intersection point of the line and the circle). Can these $1$-dimensional subspaces be identical? If not, don't they add up to $\Bbb R^2$? ... By the way, how does what you've written down give a parametrization of a line? What are $x$ and $y$?

Comment: I was assuming that OP was describing $l$ as the zero-set of a real-valued function, so the gradient of the function (which OP gets almost right, except for a sign error) is the normal to the line, so rotating it gets you a tangent to the line. Of course, $x = t, y = at$ would have been better, because then a basis for the tangent space is clearly $(1, a)$. I don't see any parameterization of the circle, but perhaps OP is planning to write one down, and differentiate it to get a tangent to $S^1$(presumably at the same point).

Comment: @JohnHughes: I wasn't talking to you, of course :P

Comment: I know ; I was just trying to excuse why I'd read through it and thought it seemed OK, when I should have been more careful like you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hints and ideas:

The geometric point of view: the tangent space of the line at a point $p$ should (and is) be a vector parallel to the line. By hypothesis the line and the circle intersect in a least one point $p.$ You can calculate the tangent spaces of the circle $S^1$ and the line $l$ at $p$ directly and show that they span $\mathbb R^2.$ One way to do this is to notice that a rotation of the circle through $\theta$ radians is a diffeomorphism, so without loss of generality, assume $p=(1,0)$. Then, $T_pS^1=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, but the line passes through the origin and so can not be tangent to the circle. To do the computation, you might use the canonical isomorphism that sends $a\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+b\frac{\partial }{\partial y }\in T_pl$ to $(a,b)\in \mathbb R^2$ and similarly for $T_pS^1$ and then observe that if $p$ is a point on the circle, the tangent space can be computed using the dot product. On the other hand, the tangent space of the line at $p$, as we mentioned, should be a vector parallel to the line and so is not tangent to the circle.

Here is a hint for a slick way if you know about differentials: with $f(x,y)=y-mx+b$ and $g(x,y)=x^2-y^2-1$, observe that $T_pl=\text{ker}\ f_*$ and $T_pS^1=\text{ker}\ g_*$.

Finally, if you know about tangent vectors as differentials of curves, you can compute the tangent spaces using them.

In any case, the basic idea is that you can actually calculate the tangent spaces and show they span $\mathbb R^2.$